# how to save custom entity with service builder liferay

Tags: liferay, hook, liferay-service-builder

how to save custom entity with service builder liferay?
i create new entity (name=BasicProfile)
and build by service builder liferay but
an exception occurred while saving.
my code :

```
    BasicProfile basicProfile = new BasicProfileImpl();
    basicProfile.setUserId(11701L);

    basicProfile.setBirthCertificateSerial(birthCertificate);
    basicProfile.setCreateDate(new Date());
    basicProfile.setFatherName(fatherName);
    basicProfile.setExtCustId(acceptorNumber);
    basicProfile.setMobileNumber(telNumber);
    basicProfile.setNationalCode(nationalCode);
   basicProfile = BasicProfileLocalServiceUtil.addBasicProfile(basicProfile);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! It would be really great if you can post some more details which will help us help you rather than having us solve the puzzled question before answering. Would help if you could provide: 1) Exception details, on which line did it occur 2) service.xml 3) liferay version etc Thanks.

Comment: "an exception occurred" without giving the exception type, message and line where it actually occurs, does not enable us to help you. Please add the information, as well as what Advaita Gosvami asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your BasicProfileLocalServiceImpl.java create the following method:

   ```
   public BasicProfile create(long userId, String birthCertificate, String fatherName, String acceptorNumber, String telNumber, String nationalCode) throws Exception {
       long id = counterLocalService.increment();
       BasicProfile obj = createBasicProfile(id);
       obj.setUserId(userId);
       obj.setBirthCertificateSerial(birthCertificate);
       obj.setCreateDate(new Date());
       obj.setFatherName(fatherName);
       obj.setExtCustId(acceptorNumber);
       obj.setMobileNumber(telNumber);
       obj.setNationalCode(nationalCode);
       obj = updateProduct(obj);
       return obj;
   }
   ```
2. Then in your code call that method to create a new object:

   ```
   BasicProfile basicProfile = BasicProfileLocalServiceUtil.create(userId, birthCertificate, fatherName, acceptorNumber, telNumber, nationalCode);
   ```